# How we can get FFMPEG command from aftereffect json file(exported from bodymovin)?

Tags: ffmpeg, after-effects, android-ffmpeg, bodymovin, pyffmpeg

How we can get FFMPEG command from aftereffect json file(exported from bodymovin)?
I have export aftereffect json file with help of bodymovin plugin.
But I have to load animation with help of ffmpeg.

How I can get ffmpeg command from json or any other way?